# Optional error while connecting openvpn client

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, openvpn

Error while running OpenVPN client in client-server,
Options error: Parameter ca_file can only be specified in TLS-mode, i.e. where --tls-server or --tls-client is also specified.

I have run the command  #openvpn --config client1.ovpn inorder to connect openvpn client

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error can be misleading. In my case I had a wrong .conf file missing ["client" at the beginning of the file](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/sample/sample-config-files/client.conf#L16)